# From where can i get Light Window 2.0 or similar?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, modal-dialog

After seeing tons of web site using modal window with a nice expansion animation i wanted to use it also. I googled it and found that many people recommend to use Light Window 2.0 
For example
http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/lightwindow.html

but all sites linked to http://stickmanlabs.com/
are broken and i can't get Light window 2.0

Is anyone has a nice modal window that I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Light Window here: http://lightbox2.com/lightwindow-2-0.html

Edit:  If you just want a modal dialog box, here are several options: http://komunitasweb.com/2009/03/jquery-modal-box-round-up/

Comment: I don't think you got my question. I'm not trying to create a gallery! I just need the modal window animation (sometimes it will be for images but sometimes for just a panel)

Answer (score 1):

You can download lightwindow 2 at http://blog.clickmike.com/?p=65 since the stickmanlabs.com site is not working.